# How can I add an additional action button into the woocommerce admin order page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, admin, actions

I am using `woocommerce_admin_order_actions` hook to add an additional action like Invoice. But it is repeating many many times whereas others button are repeating once.

```php
public function add_new_list_for_action($actions, $the_order) {

  if ( $the_order->has_status( array( 'processing' ) ) ) {
       $status = $_GET['status'];
       $order_id = method_exists($the_order, 'get_id') ? $the_order->get_id() : $the_order->id;
       $actions[] = ["action" => "invoice",
                     "url" => wp_nonce_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=wip_pdf_generator&status=invoice'.$status.'&order_id=' . $order_id), 'wip_pdf_generator'),
                     "name" => "Invoice"];
    }
    return $actions;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', array($this, 'add_new_list_for_action'),1, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this below code your current active theme functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button( $actions, $order ) {

    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'processing' ) ) ) {

        // The key slug defined for your action button
        $action_slug = 'invoice';
         $status = $_GET['status'];
         $order_id = method_exists($the_order, 'get_id') ? $the_order->get_id() : $the_order->id;
        // Set the action button
        $actions[$action_slug] = array(
            'url'       => wp_nonce_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=wip_pdf_generator&status=invoice'.$status.'&order_id=' . $order_id), 'wip_pdf_generator'),
            'name'      => __( 'Invoice', 'woocommerce' ),
            'action'    => $action_slug,
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}


add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css() {
    $action_slug = "invoice"; // The key slug defined for your action button

    echo '<style>.wc-action-button-'.$action_slug.'::after { font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e029" !important; }</style>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am making an extension plugin for woocommerce use.So I am using this hook in my plugin.

Comment: @Rafiq Yes fine with custom plugin also.

Answer (score 0):

Its a common error which you are facing, infect when you attached some code with   WordPress action hock, that action hock called many time in loop so best practice which I have observed in such case it to attached the code with some conditional if/else statement which executes the code when conditions comes true. Right now in your case I have not any code to share but it will work if you know some specific condition in your code context.